# Visual bug with speech bubble on 'Share a link...'

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See screenshot from [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7382/slideshow-display-in-aperture) below

The second bubble is sitting under 'Your Answer'

[image]

Comment: This is fixed on live site now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed on dev will be in the next deployment.